# Enabling MTX on a CAP application, resulting in issues from MegacliteDestinationLoader

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

We are trying to enable MTX on a CAP application deployed via DwC Infra. Below the stack trace of the issue that occur as part of this change -

```
    ["org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sap.cds.framework.spring.config.runtime.CdsRuntimeInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader: Provider com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DwcDestinationLoader could not be instantiated","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)","tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)","tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)","tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)","tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)","tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)","tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)","tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)","tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)","tat com.sap.oneproc.masterdata.Application.main(Application.java:17)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)","tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)","tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)","tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)","tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)","Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader: Provider com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DwcDestinationLoader could not be instantiated","tat java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(Unknown Source)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.util.FacadeLocator$MockableInstance.getFacade(FacadeLocator.java:87)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.util.FacadeLocator.getFacade(FacadeLocator.java:170)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.initDestinationLoader(DestinationAccessor.java:85)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.<clinit>(DestinationAccessor.java:33)","tat com.sap.requisitioning.dwc.mtx.DwcMtxDestinationConfiguration.initializeDestinations(DwcMtxDestinationConfiguration.java:40)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.handlerregistry.HandlerRegistryTools$DescribedHandler.process(HandlerRegistryTools.java:165)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.dispatch(ServiceImpl.java:188)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.lambda$dispatchInChangeSetContext$2(ServiceImpl.java:170)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.lambda$run$0(ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.java:38)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.run(ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.java:24)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.run(ChangeSetContextRunnerImpl.java:37)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.dispatchInChangeSetContext(ServiceImpl.java:170)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.lambda$emit$1(ServiceImpl.java:158)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.RequestContextRunnerImpl.lambda$run$1(RequestContextRunnerImpl.java:152)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.RequestContextRunnerImpl.run(RequestContextRunnerImpl.java:169)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.RequestContextRunnerImpl.run(RequestContextRunnerImpl.java:151)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.ServiceImpl.emit(ServiceImpl.java:154)","tat com.sap.cds.services.ServiceDelegator.emit(ServiceDelegator.java:52)","tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.application.ApplicationLifecycleServiceImpl.applicationPrepared(ApplicationLifecycleServiceImpl.java:19)","tat com.sap.cds.framework.spring.config.runtime.CdsRuntimeInitializer.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(CdsRuntimeInitializer.java:117)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)","tat com.sap.cds.framework.spring.config.runtime.CdsRuntimeInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(CdsRuntimeInitializer.java:117)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)","tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)","t... 24 more","Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.getAsString()" because the return value of "com.google.gson.JsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive(String)" is null","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.MegacliteConfigurationLoader.lambda$getMegacliteUriFromVcap$0(MegacliteConfigurationLoader.java:64)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.MegacliteConfigurationLoader.getMegacliteUriFromVcap(MegacliteConfigurationLoader.java:65)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.MegacliteConfigurationLoader.fromVcapServices(MegacliteConfigurationLoader.java:43)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.MegacliteConfigurationLoader.fromVcapServices(MegacliteConfigurationLoader.java:35)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.DwcCfCloudPlatform.lambda$getOutboundProxyBinding$3(DwcCfCloudPlatform.java:299)","tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.DwcCfCloudPlatform.getOutboundProxyBinding(DwcCfCloudPlatform.java:308)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.DwcCfCloudPlatform.getOutboundProxyBinding(DwcCfCloudPlatform.java:289)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DwcDestinationLoader.getReuseDestinationServiceAdapter(DwcDestinationLoader.java:130)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DwcDestinationLoader.getDefaultAdapters(DwcDestinationLoader.java:116)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DwcDestinationLoader.<init>(DwcDestinationLoader.java:50)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)","tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)","t... 60 more"]
```

From the above stack trace we observe a null pointer from the file **MegacliteConfigurationLoader** that occur while parsing the vcapservices (environment variables). On verifying code from the above file we see that the parameter being looked for is 'instance-name' and this is available as part of the environment variables.

Below is the detail of the jar used and the environment variables from CF-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>dwc-cf</artifactId>
    <version>3.54.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
user-provided": [
            {
                "label": "user-provided",
                "name": "jupiter",
                "tags": [],
                "instance_guid": "uuid",
                "instance_name": "jupiter",
                "binding_guid": "uuid",
                "binding_name": null,
                "credentials": {
                    "desc": "Oneproc Jupiter",
                    "url": "https://jupiter-xxxx.cfapipath.ondemand.com"
                },
                "syslog_drain_url": "",
                "volume_mounts": []
            },
            {
                "label": "user-provided",
                "name": "megaclite",
                "tags": [],
                "instance_guid": "uuid",
                "instance_name": "megaclite",
                "binding_guid": "uuid",
                "binding_name": null,
                "credentials": {
                    "desc": "Megaclite",
                    "url": "https://megaclite-xxxx.cert.cfapipath.ondemand.com"
                },
                "syslog_drain_url": "",
                "volume_mounts": []
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Shorter snippet  -"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.getAsString()" because the return value of "com.google.gson.JsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive(String)" is null","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.MegacliteConfigurationLoader.lambda$getMegacliteUriFromVcap$0(MegacliteConfigurationLoader.java:64)"

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed, please update to version `3.59.0` of the SAP Cloud SDK.